# slide down a form inside a image-box using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm making a slide down animation on a form to which I want it to slide down inside a box formed by images on clicking send.

I want it to go inside the box when send is clicked.

I'm using jQuery but I'm not good at jQuery so need help.

Here are my codes: 
 HTML Code:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 app-form">
      <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-md-10 form-wrap">
        <form class="check">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
            <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
            <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
            </label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!--/.form-wrap-->

      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 back-box-top"></div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 back-box-bottom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

CSS Code:

```
body{
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #e49090;
}

.app-form{
    width: 67%;
    padding: 20px 45px;
    }


.form-wrap{
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    padding: 20px;
}



.back-box-top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 276px;
    z-index: -10;
    height: 300px;
    background: url("../img/box-top.png") center top 0px no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

.back-box-bottom {
    top: 359px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 255px;
    background: url("../img/box-bottom.png") center top 0px no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

jQuery Code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".btn-default").click(function(){
        $("form").slidedown();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to learn basics of jQuery.

`jQuery` provides the Slide feature in two formats:

> slideUp : used to hide element by movingUp.
>
> slideDown: used to show element by movingDown.

I think you are misunderstood the concept that's why you are using `slideDown()`.

Issues in your code:

1. its not `slidedown()` its `slideDown()`.
2. You have performed action on `submit` clicks. Although it will perform action but refresh the page. Either you use `preventDefault()` method and submit form via `JS` or use input `type=button`. In both ways you have to submit the form via `JS`.

Corrected JQ Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-default").click(function() {
    $("form").slideUp();
  })});
```

Comment: Okay. So is there anything by which i can achieve what i want. Is there any technique.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after some help i have finally figured out the solution. 
Here is the code pen demo: http://codepen.io/vikrantnegi007/pen/KdVoqM

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 app-form">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 form-wrap">
        <form class="check">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
            <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
            <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
            </label>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Submit</a>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!--/.form-wrap-->    
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 back-box-top"></div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 back-box-bottom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>   
</body>
```

CSS Code:

```
body{
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #e49090;
    margin: 0;
}

.app-form{
    width: 67%;
    padding: 20px 45px;
    }

.form-wrap{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    padding: 20px;
    bottom: -323px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    width: 79%; 
    }

.back-box-top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 276px;
    z-index: -10;
    height: 300px;
    background: url("../img/box-top.png") center top 0px no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

.back-box-bottom {
    top: 359px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 255px;
    background: url("../img/box-bottom.png") center top 0px no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".btn-default").click(function(){
                $(".form-wrap").slideToggle({
                    direction: "down"
                }, 300);    
            });
        });
```